# DataGridView, DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn not allowing multiple checks

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

Have kind of a strange problem with a `DataGridView`.
Its `DataSource` bound to a list of objects with `set; get;`
It gets the data from this source as it should with all its boolean states for the checkboxes in the datagridview.
How ever, when I try to change checkboxes in the `DataGridView`, it will only allow one checkbox to be checked at a time. a bit like radio buttons.

This is not the feature I am after, as I want to be able to check multiple numbers of the checkboxes and then maybe later save the changes that have been done to make it permanent.

Iv made this `DataGridView` twice since I thought it might be some mysterious setting that might been included.

Any idea what might cause this?

Her comes some of the code.

Sets up the DGV in a regular form just for test

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public struct TestObject
    {
        public string text { set; get; }

        public bool cbOne { set; get; }

        public bool cbTwo { set; get; }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetupDS();
    }

    private void SetupDS()
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = SetupDBdata();
    }


    private List<TestObject> SetupDBdata()
    {
        List<TestObject> list = new List<TestObject>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new TestObject() { text = i.ToString() });
        }

        return list;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
        {
            dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        }
    }
}
```

Design code

```
    partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.txt = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.cb1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        this.cb2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // dataGridView1
        // 
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.txt,
        this.cb1,
        this.cb2});
        this.dataGridView1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(651, 390);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.dataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged);
        // 
        // txt
        // 
        this.txt.DataPropertyName = "text";
        this.txt.HeaderText = "text";
        this.txt.Name = "txt";
        // 
        // cb1
        // 
        this.cb1.DataPropertyName = "cbOne";
        this.cb1.HeaderText = "cb1";
        this.cb1.Name = "cb1";
        // 
        // cb2
        // 
        this.cb2.DataPropertyName = "cbTwo";
        this.cb2.HeaderText = "cb2";
        this.cb2.Name = "cb2";
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(651, 390);
        this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn txt;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn cb1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn cb2;
}
```

Comment: could you please provide the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you use a `struct` as the underlying databound item. All the modification you've done on the records will be applied on the copy of the underlying item. You should use a class instead:

```
public class TestObject
{
  //....
}
```

The underlying mechanism will fetch the item via the **indexer** of your `List`, you know the `indexer` of your `List<TestObject>` can be like this:

```
public TestObject this[int index] {
  get { return someValue;}
  set { ... }
}
```

the `someValue` will be your `struct` instance and you know that way the return value **is just a copy** of the actual struct. So all the changes on the copy won't reflect to the actual struct. A simple test with your list can be done with this code:

```
yourList[0].text = "???"; //<--- error saying Cannot modify the return value of ... 
                          //because it is not a variable.
```

That error is notified by design, changing the data members of a copy would mean nothing, so just notify some error to prevent programmer from compiling useless code.